# ProPublica's COMPAS Data | Feature Descriptions

Tags: machine-learning, research

ProPublica kindly provided the COMPAS Recidivism data in the github: https://github.com/propublica/compas-analysis/blob/master/compas-scores-two-years-violent.csv

Most of the features are clear from their name. But there are few variables like e.g., start , end, score_text, event etc..etc. which are not clear. ...What do these variables actually mean? Does anybody have any idea? Is there any place that I can find a description of the variables?

I have contacted many researchers all are saying ProPublica doesn't provide an official codebook for the data..which makes it really difficult to use it confidently.

The owner of the dataset doesn't bother to answer.